# Alterar tamanho do gráfico do google charts na hora da impressão com @media print

Tags: css, google-charts

Coloquei um gráfico montado com Google Charts em minha página e para imprimi-lo quero reduzir seu tamanho, por uma questão de layout da impressão.
A div que recebe o gráfico é:

```
<div id="GraficoNotas" style="width: 900px; height: 400px;">
```

Criei um css para a impressão para reduzir o tamanho desta div, mas este css não está funcionando.
Segue ele aqui:

```
@media print {
body {
margin-left:0px;
}
#GraficoNotas {
width:450px;
height:200px;
}
}
```

Já tentei alterar para tamanho em porcentagem e também não resolveu.
Na hora da impressão o tamanho do gráfico fica sempre o mesmo.
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: a margem do `body` é zerada na pagina de impressão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso também aconteceu comigo.

eu consegui resolver da seguinte maneira.

```
      <div id="AreaGraf">

             <div class="Gra">
                <div id="GraficoPizza"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
 #AreaGraf{

border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;

border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; 

padding: 10px; 

display: table; 

border-collapse: separate;

width:100%

}

.Graf{

float: left;

 min-height: 1px; 

}

#GraficoPizza{

max-width: 40%;

height: auto; 

display: table; 

border-collapse: separate;

}
```